# not able to track the referring url to 404 page in cake php

Tags: cakephp, http-status-code-404

i am having a strange issue. I am seeing a lot of people visiting my 404 page of the website. but i am not able to track from where are they being referred to the 404 page.

the website has been made on cakephp framework.

in the page controller code when the page object is null we are redirecting it to the 404 page.

We are not able to find the referrence url from where the 404 page i being loaded.

the analytics gives keywords and landing pages. but we have checked all of them and none of them are going to 404

can anyone help.

www.vresorts.in

Comment: Try a custom exception handler where you add referrer infos (see https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Lib/Error/MyErrorHandler.php#L131 for an example). This will give you the page the 404 is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to know the referrer, you can use `$this->referer()`